# Segmentation fault while processing argv

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

This procedure should convert a string that contains a set of double numbers separated by comma (e.g. 7.2,9.5,-5.515) to a vector of double type.

```
  void ToDoubleVec(int d,const char* commaSeparated,double *result)
    {
        int i;      
        result[0]=atof(strtok(commaSeparated,","));
        for(i=1;i<d;i++)
            result[i]=atof(strtok(NULL,","));   
    }
```

Here is the snippet of program that calls it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc,char** argv)
    {
    ...
        int i,dim=atoi(argv[1]);
        double *lower;
        lower = malloc(dim*sizeof(double));
        ToDoubleVec(dim,argv[2],lower);
    ...
    }
```

Debugger's output:

```
40      lower = malloc(dim*sizeof(double)); 
(gdb) s
42      ToDoubleVec(dim,argv[2],lower);
(gdb) s
ToDoubleVec (d=2, commaSeparated=0x7fffffffe9d3 "2.3,-62.1", result=0x603010) at testPSO.c:11
11      result[0]=atof(strtok(commaSeparated,","));
(gdb) s

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff77f56bb in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
```

Why doesn't it work? I was sure that I've allocated enough memory for the array and also parameters seems to be passed correctly.

Comment: @JohnKugelman yes, look at the debugger's output: ToDoubleVec (d=2, commaSeparated=0x7fffffffe9d3 "2.3,-62.1", result=0x603010)

Comment: `commaSeparated` should be declared `char *` not `const char *` since strtok() modifies it. Do you not get a warning about that?

Comment: Did you include `stdlib.h`?

Comment: Brave man passing the result of `strtok()` to `atof()` without checking for null pointers...I'd expect to see crashes when `strtok()` returns null.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler but I don't think it's the problem he is facing if you look at the arguments he is passing to `ToDoubleVec`.

Comment: For debugging purpose you'd better change the crashing line to be three lines, so you can assign the error to one of the three function calls/assignments involved.

Comment: Maybe try that **`p`** feature of gdb. Knowing what those values are before each call might tell you a world of information.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler "brave" wasn't the adjective that immediately sprung forth in my mind. =P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reduce your code to this SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)), which crashes nicely when you leave out `#include <string.h>` and does not compile cleanly when you add `#include <string.h>`:

```
segv.c: In function ‘ToDoubleVec’:
segv.c:8:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strtok’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
segv.c:8:20: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
segv.c:14:20: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
```

Code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
//#include <string.h>

static void ToDoubleVec(int d, const char* commaSeparated, double *result)
{
    int i;      
    result[0] = atof(strtok(commaSeparated, ","));
    for (i = 1; i < d; i++)
        result[i] = atof(strtok(NULL, ","));   
}

int main(void)
{
    int dim = 2;
    double *lower = malloc(dim*sizeof(double));
    char arg[] = "7.2,9.5,-5.515";
    ToDoubleVec(dim, arg, lower);
}
```

Passing the return value from a function such as `strtok()` which can return a null pointer directly to a function such as `atof()` which does not tolerate null pointers is foolhardy; it leads to crashes.  If everything is correct, you'll be OK; if not, you'll crash and burn.

The unchecked memory allocation is a similar problem; you didn't even check that `dim` was non-zero (and non-negative) before doing the memory allocation in the original.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void ToDoubleVec(int d, char *commaSeparated, double *result)
{
    int i;      
    char *number = strtok(commaSeparated, ",");
    if (number != 0)
    {
        result[0] = atof(number);
        for (i = 1; i < d; i++)
        {
            number = strtok(NULL, ",");
            if (number != 0)
                result[i] = atof(number);
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int dim = 2;
    double *lower = malloc(dim*sizeof(double));
    char arg[] = "7.2,9.5,-5.515";
    assert(lower != 0);
    ToDoubleVec(dim, arg, lower);
}
```

You could — and in one version of the code I did — add error printing to report if the tests on `number` failed.  But the crash is caused by the implicit declaration of `strtok()` as returning `int` and not `char *`.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to compile your code, and the compiler warned me that strtok() takes as input a char* and not a const char*. Then I have tried this code, and it is working correctly:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void ToDoubleVec(int d, char* commaSeparated,double *result);


int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
    int i,dim=atoi(argv[1]);
    double *lower;
    lower = malloc(dim*sizeof(double));
    ToDoubleVec(dim,argv[2],lower);
    for (i=0; i<dim; ++i) {
        printf("%f\n", lower[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

void ToDoubleVec(int d, char* commaSeparated,double *result)
{
    int i;
    result[0]=atof(strtok(commaSeparated,","));
    for(i=1;i<d;i++)
        result[i]=atof(strtok(NULL,","));
}
```

So try to change const char* to char*, and check the input you pass to your program, maybe it is not correct and this could be the problem.